# Timer is still firing after Clicking on other Links in GWT

Tags: gwt, timer

So I have a timer and it keeps on firing even though I cleared the Panel and loaded other model... my question is, how to cancel a timer when I unload a model?

So here is part of my code

```
public Display(List<Clarification> result) {

    if (result.size() == 0) {
        Window.alert("EMPTY");
    } else {


        RootPanel.get("Dev1").clear();
         t = new Timer() {
            public void run() {

                cd = new ClarificationDispatcher();
                cd.getClarificationsCount(result.size());
            }
        };
        t.scheduleRepeating(5000);
```

}

I tried to cancel the Timer onUnload() method however, I don't believe it is getting called at all...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by other model? please share some code. You can use `timer.cancel()` to cancel a timer but at least tell me when to stop it? What panel are you talking about?

Comment: I want to stop it when I leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps to follow

- use `window.onunload` event that is called when page is refreshed
- first export `cancelTimer()` method to java script using JSNI and register `cancelTimerFunction` as java script function that is called on page unload
- cancel timer on window close

Code:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

private static Timer timer = null;

public void onModuleLoad() {
    exportCancelTimer();

    final Label label = new Label("Hello ");
    timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            label.setText("Hello " + Math.random() * 100);
        }

    };

    timer.scheduleRepeating(500);
    RootPanel.get().add(label);

    Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

        @Override
        public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

}


public static void cancelTimer() {
    if (timer != null) {
        System.out.println("cancel");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}

public static native void exportCancelTimer() /*-{
    $wnd.cancelTimerFunction = $entry(@com.x.y.z.GWTProject::cancelTimer());
    $wnd.onunload = $wnd.cancelTimerFunction;
}-*/;
```