# When is Widget OnUnload() is called?

Tags: gwt

Can you please tell me when a widget's OnUnload() is called?

I tried to override it however, it is never been accessed. Also what is the best way to unload a composite, I am using RootPanel.get("Dev1").clear();

Comment: Are you talking about full page unload or just single widget clear on page? Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310407/timer-is-still-firing-after-clicking-on-other-links-in-gwt/22311180#22311180)

Comment: Please let me know what you want to achieve? What is you design?

Comment: I am clearing a vertical panel that has many widgets inside of it. I was to be able to reach the method OnUnload() so that I setup static values. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share a sample code?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the timer when you leave the page then use `CloseHandler`.
This handler is called while page closing and refreshing.

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
});
```

---

If you want to stop the timer when clearing a vertical panel then use `removeFromParent`.

This overridden method is to be called when any widget is removed form its parent.

```
private Timer timer = null;

/*
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Label label = new Label("Hello ") {
        @Override
        public void removeFromParent() {
            if (timer != null && this.isAttached()) {
                timer.cancel();
                System.out.println("timer is stopped");
            }
            super.removeFromParent();
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            label.setText("Hello " + (int) (Math.random() * 100));
        }

    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(500);

    final VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    verticalPanel.add(label);

    Button button = new Button("Remove Label");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            label.removeFromParent();
        }
    });
    verticalPanel.add(button);

    RootPanel.get().add(verticalPanel);
}
```

---

As per you comments try below code where `clear` method is overridden for `VerticalPanel`.

```
    final VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel(){
        @Override 
        public void clear(){
            if(this.isAttached()){
                timer.cancel();
            }
            super.clear();
        }
    };
    verticalPanel.getElement().setId("Div1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I accomplish this without having a 'Remove' button? I want this to be called once a composite is cleared using RootPanel.get("Dev1").clear();

Comment: Where is `Dev1` is defined in your html/jsp file or java file?

Comment: I have updated my code as per your comments. Please let me whether It solve it or not. Please correct if I am wrong. You have `VerticalPanel` and you want to set some static variable when its `clear` method is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot Braj! and yes exactly! Also please be informed that I tried your code but it didn't work. I really appreciate your help!